# i must write code which check user have advert on site, if no function must $out (return $out;)

Tags: php, wordpress

i must write code which check if user have advert on site, if not then the function must return $out :

```
if(get_post() 'post_type'=>'advert'||'post_status'=>'publish'<1) {    
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO, please take a quick [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and have a quick look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: maybe this ?<?php $args = array(
 
 'post_status'=> 'publish',
 'post type'=> 'advert' 
 );
 $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>

Comment: `$post = get_post( 7 );    if(!empty($post) && $post->post_type =='advert' && $post->post_status=='publish'){  return $out;}`

Comment: why get_post have number 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this :

```
if(get_posts(array('post_type'=>'advert','post_status'=>'publish'))) {
 return $out;
}
```

Comment: i need in order to user must only for first time wait for moderator who accept. if he have first advert accept, next dont need it